# Weird Wireless Issue on 12.04

Tags: drivers, intel-wireless

I am having this weird issue with my wireless card (Intel Centrino Wireless n130).
If I restart the computer via the  interface when it restarts it doesn't seem to recognize my wifi card. However when I press the power button to restart my computer it works! I honestly can't figure out why. However once I do have it working it works perfectly fine :S just having a problem at startup it seems. I want to fix the program so that I'm not pressing the power button to turn on/off and restart my computer constantly.

I am new to Ubuntu so please be gentle. Lol

Comment: Can you elaborate more as in what you meant by the interface?? is it terminal you referring to??

Comment: I meant through the operating system clicking the cog on the right top corner and hitting shut down

Answer (score 0):

Problems with Wireless cards are common, due to the large number of cards.

As you are using Ubuntu 12.04, this version permits you upgrade your kernel to the
ones used by the new versions of ubuntu, such Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander). So you
just need to install the new kernel from the command line:

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-saucy`

This will install the kernel version 3.11. Normally installing the new versions of the kernel sanes the problems with wireless cards.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this didn't work

Comment: did you restart the system an boot from the new kernel?

Comment: Yeap currently booting 3.11.0.19

Comment: Well, Ubuntu 14.04 it's out and it's LTS as well. You might wanna try [Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Comment: I thought the same thing and installed 14.04 and still have the same problem. I'm starting to think it might be a hardware problem.